# How do I compare two rows from a SQL database table based on DateTime within 3 seconds?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table of DetailRecords containing records that seem to be "duplicates" of other records, but they have a unique primary key [ID]. I would like to delete these "duplicates" from the DetailRecords table and keep the record with the longest/highest Duration. I can tell that they are linked records because their DateTime field is within 3 seconds of another row's DateTime field and the Duration is within 2 seconds of one another. Other data in the row will also be duplicated exactly, such as Number, Rate, or AccountID, but this could be the same for the data that is not "duplicate" or related.

```
CREATE TABLE #DetailRecords (
    [AccountID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ID] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [DateTime] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Duration] INT NULL,
    [Number] VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [Rate] DECIMAL(8,6) NULL    
);
```

I know that I will most likely have to perform a self join on the table, but how can I find two rows that are similar within a DateTime range of plus or minus 3 seconds, instead of just exactly the same?
I am having the same trouble with the Duration within a range of plus or minus 2 seconds.

Comment: Is it possible to modify your schema so that the DateTime column is stored as a DateTime value rather than a varchar?  That would make comparisons easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is taking the absolute value of the difference between the dates and durations.  I don't know SQL server, but here's how I'd do it in SQLite.  The technique should be the same, only the specific function names will be different.

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM   DetailRecords a
JOIN   DetailRecords b
  ON   a.id > b.id
WHERE  abs(strftime("%s", a.DateTime) - strftime("%s", b.DateTime)) <= 3
  AND  abs(a.duration - b.duration) <= 2
```

Taking the absolute value of the difference covers the "plus or minus" part of the range.  The self join is on `a.id > b.id` because `a.id = b.id` would duplicate every pair.

Given the entries...

```
ID|DateTime           |Duration
1 |2014-01-26T12:00:00|5
2 |2014-01-26T12:00:01|6
3 |2014-01-26T12:00:06|6
4 |2014-01-26T12:00:03|11
5 |2014-01-26T12:00:02|10
6 |2014-01-26T12:00:01|6
```

I get the pairs...

```
5|4
2|1
6|1
6|2
```

And you should really store those dates as DateTime types if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solution worked for me. I also changed my DateTime to a DateTime type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self-referential CTE and compare the DateTime fields.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT AccountID,
       ID,
       DateTime,
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID, ID, <insert any other matching keys> ORDER BY AccountID)
FROM table
)
SELECT earliestAccountID = c1.AccountID,
       earliestDateTime = c1.DateTime,
       recentDateTime = c2.DateTime,
       recentAccountID = c2.AccountID
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2
      ON c1.rn = 1 AND c2.rn = 2 AND c1.DateTime <> c2.DateTime
```

**Edit**

I made several assumptions about the data set, so this may not be as relevant as you need. If you're simply looking for difference between possible duplicates, specifically DateTime differences, this will work. However, this does not constrain to your date range, nor does it automatically assume what the DateTime column is used for or how it is set.

Comment: I think you have a bug in the earliestDateTime CASE clause. Should it be `THEN c1.DateTime ELSE c2.DateTime END`?

Comment: @Schwern no, it needs to be `THEN c1.DateTime ELSE c1.DateTime`. Essentially, you're ensuring you get the earliest `DateTime` no matter what. `c1` references the earliest created Account, due to the ordering in the CTE. So if `c1` and `c2` are equal, then it doesn't matter which one you display, so i chose `c1`. If they don't equal (`ELSE`), then *definitely* choose `c1`. Either way, you end up with the earliest created `DateTime`

Comment: "If they're equal, choose c1. Else choose c1."  Why the case at all?  Wouldn't `earliestDateTime = c1.DateTime` do the trick?

Comment: @Schwern yes it would. Although from the OP it sounds like sometimes they may be the same, and sometimes even if `DateTime` is different, the record may not be a duplicate. The question was regarding looking at the differences and easily deleting. The query I posted allows the user to look at each row to determine if they're a duplicate.

Comment: So... remove that bit of obfuscation? I'm having trouble finding where in your answer you handle the range part of the question.

Comment: @Schwern I edited the response to address the differing DateTimes. Essentially any columns used to `PARTITION` the rows will count as matching criteria. If the `Number`, `Rate`, and `AccountID` columns all match, OP could `PARTITION` by those columns to find exact duplicates, whether they were created within seconds of each other or years apart.

Comment: I can't see how the CTE is ordered by DateTime. Are you assuming the DateTime will increase with AccountID? And assuming the select on cte will run in a certain order without an order by? As for finding the duplicates, the OP said there are reasons why the other columns would be duplicated so that cannot be relied on. *Other data in the row will also be duplicated exactly, such as Number, Rate, or AccountID, but this could be the same for the data that is not "duplicate" or related.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69685/discussion-between-schwern-and-phoenix).